# On a Mac, how can I list contents of a non-current directory without showing backup files (ending with ~), preferably with BSD command ls?

Tags: command-line, terminal, osx, ls, options

My system:

- OS: MacOS / Mac OS X (Mojave 10.14.5)
- OS core: Darwin (18.6.0)
- Kernel: Darwin Kernel / XNU (18.6.0 / xnu-4903.261.4~2/RELEASE_X86_64)
- ls: version unknown, but `man ls` gives a page from the BSD General Commands Manual
- Shells:

  - Bash: GNU bash, version 5.0.7(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0)
  - Zsh: zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0)

In MacOS, in a terminal CLI using a shell such as bash or zsh, I'd like to use the (BSD) command `ls` (or perhaps a similarly common and useful tool) to list the contents of a directory other than the current working directory, where all files except those ending with a tilde (`~`) are shown.

Excluding the last stipulation, `ls` naturally accomplishes this task when the non-current directory is used as an argument to `ls`: `ls arg` where `arg` is an absolute or relative path to the non-current directory (such as `/absolute/path/to/directory`, `~/path/from/home/to/directory`, or `path/from/current/dir/to/directory`).

I know how to list non-backup contents in the current directory, using filename expansion (aka "globbing") and the `-d` option (to list directories and not their contents), like so: `ls -d *[^~]` (or `ls -d *[!~]`).  I want the same sort of results, but for a non-current directory.

I can almost achieve what I want by using `ls -d arg/*[^~]`, where `arg` is the same as described above, but the results show the path to each content element (ie, each file and directory in the directory of interest).  I want `ls` to display each element without the path to it, like is done with `ls arg`.

In Linux, using the GNU command `ls`, I can achieve exactly what I want using the `-B` option to not list backup files: `ls -B arg`.  Although this is what I want, I'd like to achieve this using tools native to MacOS, preferably the BSD `ls`.

Note: I do not want to use `grep` (eg, `ls arg | grep '.*[^~]$'`), because `grep` changes the formatting and coloring of the output.

Question recap:  On a Mac, how can I list the contents of a non-current directory but not the backup files, preferably using `ls`?

Comment: Isn't `ls arg | grep --color=always '.*[^~]$'` good enough?

Comment: @ChatterOne: Using `grep` with `--color-always` is not appropriate for my purposes because it changes the formatting and coloring of the output.  I want it to behave just like `ls`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could execute `ls` in a subshell:

```
(cd arg; ls -d *[^~])
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `bash` and its `GLOBIGNORE` shell variable, together with macOS's `basename`:

```
$ mkdir dir
$ touch dir/file{1,2}{,~}
$ ls -R
dir

./dir:
file1   file1~  file2   file2~
```

```
$ GLOBIGNORE=*~
$ ls -d dir/*
dir/file1       dir/file2
```

```
$ basename -a dir/*
file1
file2
```

Setting `GLOBIGNORE` to a list of `:`-delimited patterns will make filename completion ignore those patterns.

The `basename` utility in macOS accepts more than one pathname if you use its `-a` option, and will return a list consisting of only the filename portions of those pathnames.

Instead of using `GLOBIGNORE` (which provides a more generic way to ignore certain filename pattern expansions) you could obviously use your pattern `*[!~]` (note that `!` negates a character class in the shell, while `^` negates a character class in regular expressions):

```
unset GLOBIGNORE
basename -a dir/*[!~]
```

... or, you could just install GNU coreutils from Homebrew and use `gls -B` as you may be used to on Linux systems.

Comment: Unfortunately, `basename` changes the format and coloring of the output, so it does not meet my requirements.

Comment: I'm having trouble with your solution.  After executing `GLOBIGNORE=*~`, I can use `set | grep GLOBIGNORE` to see that I have affected the variable: `GLOBIGNORE='*~'`.  And executing `echo "$GLOBIGNORE"` shows `*~`.  But when I use your suggested commands above, they do not leave out the files ending with a tilde (even when using `/bin/ls` rather than `ls`).

Comment: Also, is it a bad idea or "bad habit" to use `^` instead of `!` in the globbing pattern?  Maybe I should change the `^` characters to `!` characters in my question (and answer).

Comment: @zeroparallax I just tested my solution with the default tools on macOS Mojave 10.14.5, and it behaves as I have described.  The `bash` shell understands `[^...]` but the standard syntax is `[!...]` for filename globbing patterns.

Answer (score 1):

The concise answer is to use a subshell to execute the command in the non-current directory:

```
(cd arg; ls -d *[^~])
```

But to create a general function that works for the current directory as well as any non-current directory, we can add the following to `.bashrc` (or to `bashrc_aliases_lsBSD`, sourced by `.bashrc`):

```
alias ls='/bin/ls'
alias   l=''
unalias l
function l () { ( if [[ -n "$@" ]]; then cd "$@"; fi ; /bin/ls -d *[^~] ) }
```

If we defy the preference mentioned above for using BSD, we can use GNU `ls` without any problems by installing the GNU core utilities (eg, via `brew install coreutils`) and creating the desired aliases (instead of using the code above) in `.bashrc` (or in `bashrc_aliases_lsGNU`, sourced by `.bashrc`):

```
alias ls='/usr/local/bin/gls'
alias l='/usr/local/bin/gls -B'
```

My own current solution is to use both of these constructions and switch between them when desired using a variable I call `LS_TYPE` and a function I call `ls-switch` (defined in `bashrc_aliases`, sourced by `.bashrc`), which sources one of two config files containing these two constructions:

```
function ls-switch () {
    if [[ $LS_TYPE = "GNU" ]] ; then
        LS_TYPE="BSD"
        source ~/.config/bash/bashrc_aliases_lsBSD
    elif [[ $LS_TYPE = "BSD" ]] ; then
        LS_TYPE="GNU"
        source ~/.config/bash/bashrc_aliases_lsGNU
    fi
}
```

With this arrangement, the default behaviors of `ls` and `l` are set in `.bashrc` with the first definition of `LS_TYPE` and choosing which config file to source, for example:

```
LS_TYPE="BSD"
source ~/.config/bash/bashrc_aliases_lsBSD
```

Comment: It would be more convenient to detect which `ls` is available automatically. Something like: `LS_TYPE=unknown; case $(uname -s) in Darwin*|*BSD*) LS_TYPE=BSD; esac; if type gls >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then alias ls=gls; LS_TYPE=GNU; else case "$(ls --version -1 -d / 2>&1)" in *GNU*) LS_TYPE=GNU;; esac` (untested code, just to give an idea of how to do it)